# "Failed to load resource" errors for .js and .css files when running Rails application offline in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get a Rails application to work offline. The application appears to work OK when online.

In Chrome, when the server is running, I see this from the Chrome console when I run the application (portions snipped). :

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest
http://localhost:3000/application.manifest
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache Downloading event
...
Application Cache Progress event (5 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/todos.css.scss
Application Cache Progress event (6 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css
Application Cache Progress event (7 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/todos.js.coffee
Application Cache Progress event (8 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.tmpl.js
Application Cache Progress event (9 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.offline.js
...
Application Cache Progress event (11 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js
...
Application Cache Progress event (13 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/json.js
Application Cache Progress event (14 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/scaffolds.css.scss
Application Cache Progress event (15 of 16) http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js
Application Cache Progress event (16 of 16) 
Application Cache UpdateReady event
```

However, offline I see this (again, some snipped). Note that the `GET` lines are load errors.:

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://localhost:3000/application.manifest
Application Cache Checking event
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css?body=1  todos:5
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1  todos:6
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/todos.css?body=1  todos:7
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1  todos:8
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1  todos:8
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.offline.js?body=1  todos:8
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.tmpl.js?body=1  todos:8
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/json.js?body=1  todos:8
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/offline.js?body=1  todos:8
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/todos.js?body=1  todos:8
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1  todos:8
Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (-1) http://localhost:3000/application.manifest
```

In particular, I notice `?body=1` is appended to the file name when offline.

**Environment:**

- Rails: 3.2.8
- ruby 1.9.3p194
- WEBrick: 1.3.1
- MySQL: 5.5.28 MySQL Community Server
- Chrome: Version 22.0.1229.94 m
- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

**Gems** (the gems I think are relevant):

- jquery-rails (2.1.3)
- json (1.7.5, 1.5.4)
- rack-offline (0.6.4)
- sprockets (2.1.3)

**Application Manifest**:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# ef05db1f746b226b3eb8b3673d65d3585eb8a9e1e35f79a6fc9d90693ff9a569
404.html
422.html
500.html
index.html
assets/application.js
assets/jquery.js
assets/jquery.offline.js
assets/jquery.tmpl.js
assets/json.js
assets/todos.js.coffee
assets/application.css
assets/scaffolds.css.scss
assets/todos.css.scss

NETWORK:
/
```

**application.html.erb**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/application.manifest">
<head>
    <title>TestOffsite</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**todos_controller.erb** (snipped):

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /todos
  # GET /todos.json
  respond_to :html, :json   

  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
respond_with(@todos)
    #respond_to do |format|
    #  format.html # index.html.erb
    #  format.json { render json: @todos }
    #end
  end
...
```

**Contents of manifest.yml**:

```
---
rails.png: rails-be8732dac73d845ac5b142c8fb5f9fb0.png
application.js: application-39fb9cbdc400e6885a41059ea60f3851.js
application.css: application-0149f820dbdd285aa65e241569d8c256.css
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: weird try compiling your asset and then give it a try I have done it for `sinatra` app and the above work like charm check this `http://html5cache.herokuapp.com/'

Comment: I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. Same result.

Comment: FYI did you added the precompile version of js in the application.manifest

Comment: I'm not sure. I believe the application.manifest is generated through the require instructions in application.js. Those instructions are `//= require jquery`, `//= require jquery_ujs` and `//= require_tree .`. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: just to correct you it `manifest.yml` not `application.manifest`

Comment: I added contents of `manifest.yml` above.

Comment: It has to be something like [this](http://html5cache.herokuapp.com/cache.manifest)

Comment: the `manifest.yml` thing that you pasted Is something like used by sprokets i guess

Answer (score 0):

To make my local environment pull assets from the app/assets/* directory instead of /public/assets I have to set the following in development.rb:

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed (ON for Heroku)
  # config.assets.compile = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS (ON for Heroku)
  # config.assets.compress = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs (ON for Heroku)
  # config.assets.digest = true

  # Don't pull public assets in development mode - remove to check CDN/S3 assets (OFF for Heroku)
  config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server (ON for Heroku)
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn%d.mydomain.com"
```

When it's ready to go on my Heroku staging server it looks like this:

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed (ON for Heroku)
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS (ON for Heroku)
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs (ON for Heroku)
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Don't pull public assets in development mode - remove to check CDN/S3 assets (OFF for Heroku)
  # config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server (ON for Heroku)
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn%d.mydomain.com"
```

I do this frequently - flipping them back and forth - as sometimes I want to check to make sure that CloudFront is serving newly pushed assets, and sometimes I just want local speed and the ability to develop my CSS or JS files.